# How can I draw gradient arrows on iso-contour

Tags: pgfplots, contour

Using pgfplots I draw the isocontour of a function f(x,y): lines such as f(x,y)=C with C a chosen number.

See below example with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85]
    \begin{axis}[   xmin=-4,xmax=12, ymin=-4,ymax=4,x=1cm,y=1cm,at={(-4cm,-4cm)}]]
    \addplot +[no markers,
    raw gnuplot,
    thick,dashed,
    empty line = jump, % not strictly necessary, as this is the default behaviour in the development version of PGFPlots
    ] gnuplot {
        set contour base;
        set cntrparam levels discrete -2,-1.1,-1.4;
        unset surface;
        set view map;
        set isosamples 500;
        set samples 500;
        splot -2/sqrt((x-7.5)^2+y^2)-3/sqrt((x-0.5)^2+y^2);
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: isocontour]
I can draw the gradient vectors at any given point but I don't know how to place them at different locations on the isocontour curve.

[image]

How could I get the positions of various point on that dashed blue curve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that you can access the coordinates of the contour plots. Since these are several disconnected segments, specifying `pos` does not suffice. Rather, you need to also use `pos segment`, which is explained on p. 358 of the pgfplots manual v1.16. It is, however, not a priori clear which segment has which index. To simplify matters, I added a style that adds the gradient arrow, which is orthogonal to the tangent of the contour at this point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[gradient arrow/.style={
 insert path={coordinate[pos=#1,sloped,
     above=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ga/above}]  (aux-1)
    coordinate[pos=#1,sloped,
     above=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ga/above}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ga/length}] (aux-2)
    (aux-1) edge[/tikz/ga/arrow] 
    (aux-2)}},ga/.cd,
    above/.initial=3pt,
    length/.initial=12pt,
    arrow/.style={-stealth,black,solid,thick}]
  \begin{axis}[scale=0.85,xmin=-4,xmax=12, ymin=-4,ymax=4,x=1cm,y=1cm,at={(-4cm,-4cm)}]]
   \addplot +[no markers,name=contour,
    raw gnuplot,
    thick,dashed,
    empty line = jump, % not strictly necessary, as this is the default behaviour in the development version of PGFPlots
    ] gnuplot {
        set contour base;
        set cntrparam levels discrete -2,-1.1,-1.4;
        unset surface;
        set view map;
        set isosamples 500;
        set samples 500;
        splot -2/sqrt((x-7.5)^2+y^2)-3/sqrt((x-0.5)^2+y^2);
    } 
    [pos segment=1]
    [gradient arrow/.list={0.2,0.8}]
    [pos segment=3,/tikz/ga/arrow/.append style={red},/tikz/ga/length=10pt]
    [gradient arrow/.list={0.2,0.8}];
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I don't get the same output than you using your code. All arrows point toward the bottom left corner.

Comment: @JulienFaure All I can say is that the result presented here emerged from running `pdflatex -shell-escape` on the above TeX file.

Comment: This is strange. I get very different arrows with the exact same code. I really don't get how it could be different. I cannot add picture to comments but I may send it to you directly.